# Error whilst making a simple XOR crypter in c

Tags: c, file, encryption, xor

**There are no compile errors just functionality**

I was attempting to make a simple XOR crypter in c. I found out that the crypting part is not a problem because when the XOR function is used twice on the same string it returns the the exact string I sent back. The problem I believe is therefore not with the crypting part, I believe that the problem occurs when writing the file.

**Function the error is within**

```
int xorFile (char *infile, char *outfile) {
    FILE *in,
         *out;
    long lSize;
    char *buffer;

    in = fopen ( infile , "rb" );
    out = fopen(outfile, "wb");

    if( !in ) perror(infile),exit(1);

    fseek( in , 0L , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell( in );
    rewind( in );

    /* allocate memory for entire content */
    buffer = (char*)calloc( 1, lSize+1 );
    if( !buffer ) fclose(in),fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr),exit(1);

    /* copy the file into the buffer */
    if( 1!=fread( buffer , lSize, 1 , in) )
      fclose(in),free(buffer),fputs("entire read fails",stderr),exit(1);

    /* do your work here, buffer is a string contains the whole text */
    int i;
    for(i=0;buffer[i]!='\0';i++) {
        fputc(buffer[i] ^ XOR_KEY,out);
    }
    fclose(in);
    free(buffer);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;

}
```

**What I believe causes the error**

```
int i;
for(i=0;buffer[i]!='\0';i++) {
    fputc(buffer[i] ^ XOR_KEY,out);
}
```

**Full Program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define XOR_KEY 0x6F

int xorFile (char *infile, char *outfile) {
    FILE *in,
         *out;
    long lSize;
    char *buffer;

    in = fopen ( infile , "rb" );
    out = fopen(outfile, "wb");

    if( !in ) perror("blah.txt"),exit(1);

    fseek( in , 0L , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell( in );
    rewind( in );

    /* allocate memory for entire content */
    buffer = (char*)calloc( 1, lSize+1 );
    if( !buffer ) fclose(in),fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr),exit(1);

    /* copy the file into the buffer */
    if( 1!=fread( buffer , lSize, 1 , in) )
      fclose(in),free(buffer),fputs("entire read fails",stderr),exit(1);

    /* do your work here, buffer is a string contains the whole text */
    int i;
    for(i=0;buffer[i]!='\0';i++) {
        fputc(buffer[i] ^ XOR_KEY,out);
    }
    fclose(in);
    free(buffer);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc <= 2) {

      fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s [IN FILE] [OUT FILE]\n" , argv[0]) ;

      exit (1);
    }

    xorFile (argv[1], argv[2]) ;
}
```

**Tested causes**

- Checked on multiple OS's
- Checked on different file formats
- Checked on different privileges
- Checked on different compilers as well(ran out of things to test)

**Additional infomation**
When I encrypted a copy of the source file and decrypted it, all that remained was `#include <std`

Comment: FWIW, I ran your code and it worked fine for me. The output file was exactly the same as the input file.

Comment: @TomKarzes: The second part of your question cannot happen. He allocates `lSize+1` with `calloc` (which zeros memory) then only reads `lSize`. The first part of your question is still valid.

Comment: What damnt it I don't know why it doesn't work for me in linux and windows.

Comment: Thanks @TomKarzes any Idea how to fix it. I've got no clue I always use '\0' don't know what to do without it.

Comment: I replaced my comments with a posted answer, including a more detailed explanation of why it was causing the behavior you observed.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc family in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is caused by your loop exiting prematurely.  The following test will stop as soon as it encounters a null byte:

```
for(i=0;buffer[i]!='\0';i++)
```

To encrypt the entire file, this needs to be changed to:

```
for(i=0;i<lSize;i++)
```

This will be a problem not only for non-text files, but also for decrypting, since the encryption process will introduce zero bytes for any characters that match your XOR_KEY.  For instance, if your XOR_KEY is `0x69`, which is an ascii `'i'`, your encrypted file will contain a zero byte in place of each `'i'`.  When decrypting it, it will cut the file off at the first such character, which explains what you've been seeing.  This will correct that.

Comment: Say I create a an obfuscated exe with this. That exe won't be runnable would it? I need a way to decrypt it before running. Am I right?

Comment: Correct, it almost certainly won't be runnable as long as the key is non-zero.  Keep in mind, however, that this encryption is very weak and would be fairly trivial for someone to break.

Answer (score 1):

```
buffer[i] ^= XOR_KEY;
fputc(buffer[i] ^ XOR_KEY,out);
```

First, the program looks at the character in `buffer[i]`, XORs it, and stores the XORed character back in `buffer[i]`.

Then, it looks at the character in `buffer[i]` (which is now XORed), XORs it again, and writes *that* to `out`.

So the character that gets written to `out` has been XORed twice - so it's just the original character.

Comment: Crap thanks for pointing that out. That was a demo to see if it wasn't an output problem, I will change it now. Thanks